# Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am trying to use UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {}
```

But I have error: `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIViewController'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You don't use the brackets in Swift,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {}
```